# How to Open a JEE, STRUTS, and Oracle ADF Project Without .jws or .jpr Files in Oracle JDeveloper Studio?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle-adf

Good afternoon,

I've encountered a challenge with a project handed to me. It's structured with JEE, STRUTS, and Oracle ADF. Initially, I attempted to work with it in IntelliJ. However, upon reviewing the code, it became apparent that there might be dependencies on specific files or configurations related to Oracle ADF.

To address this, I downloaded Oracle JDeveloper Studio, which is tailored for ADF development. However, upon attempting to open the project within JDeveloper, I found that only directories were visible, lacking essential files such as .jws or .jpr.

Despite thoroughly combing through the project directories, I couldn't locate these critical files. I'm seeking guidance on how to properly set up or configure the project within Oracle JDeveloper Studio or any other appropriate tooling.

Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[JDeveloper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQVX.png)

```
Actions Taken:
    Initially, I attempted to work with the project using IntelliJ IDEA, a popular integrated development environment (IDE).
    Upon realizing potential dependencies on Oracle ADF-specific configurations, I downloaded Oracle JDeveloper Studio, a specialized IDE for ADF development.
    I attempted to open the project within JDeveloper Studio to leverage its ADF-centric features.

Expected Outcome:
    I anticipated that upon opening the project in Oracle JDeveloper Studio, I would see the project structure along with necessary files such as .jws or .jpr files.
    These files are crucial for ADF projects as they contain configuration information and project settings.
    With these files present, I expected to be able to work with the project seamlessly within JDeveloper Studio, leveraging its ADF-specific capabilities.
```

However, despite these efforts, I found that only directories were visible in the project, and the essential files (.jws or .jpr) were missing. This situation prompted me to seek guidance on how to properly set up or configure the project within Oracle JDeveloper Studio or any other suitable tooling.

[codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVDKF.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. First, you need to find out if you have the source code of the application or project. The image you shared only shows some deployment stuff but no source code.

If you don't have the source, it's nearly impossible to reconstruct the project from the ear or war files.

The next problem is that you need to know the version of JDev the application was created with. Struts development with JDeveloper is not supported in all versions. JDeveloper 12c has no struts development support. So, the software you have installed will not be able to compile or run the project.

Once you know the JDev version used to develop the project, you need to get this version of JDeveoper or any newer version that supports migrating old struts projects to the newer version. You can find this information in the release notes of each version.

Comment: Yes, friend, I have the code. I opened the project for the first time in IntelliJ, where I reviewed the code and realized the ADF dependencies. I researched what it was because I didn't know anything about ADF. Now, I'm trying to open the project directly with JDeveloper 12c, but it won't let me because it requires a .jws or .jpr file which are not found in the repository. However, I do have access to the code, but I open it from IntelliJ or from VSCode. I need to work on it from JDeveloper 12. Do you know how I can find out the version?

Comment: Do you know which JDev version was used to create the application?

You can't use  JDev 12c if the app has been created using JDev 10g!